# Node.js Add-on with C++ for SHA512 generation

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, sha512, node.js-addon

I want to create a add-on in C++ which will generate SHA512 of the string passed to the function in it. This C++ file will also contain one key which will be used during hash generation. My requirement is that I want to call this add-on from Node.js and expect the hash in return from this library.

I am totally new to this. I have tried sample examples of add-ons of hello world and some addition of numbers, but have no knowledge to create my own functions. I have C++ files which are used for hash generation but don't know how to bind it all.

I am pasting the link where C++ code files are available:

http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha512-function

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Is it just about learning? Because you can already create that with the buildin `crypto`. For writing plugins I would use the [Native Abstractions for Node.js](https://github.com/nodejs/nan), they also have an example how to create a plugin here [Node Native Extension Boilerplate](https://github.com/fcanas/node-native-boilerplate).

Comment: Its not just for learning, I want to implement this. Whole idea is that the hash generation code should not be visible to anyone so went for add-on option.

Comment: Sounds a bit like _security through obscurity_ and this normally not worth the effort. But that's up to you to decide that. But be award, that for such a small module it won't be a big deal to do the reverse engineering and to extract the used _key_.

Comment: Yes we are trying to get to security through obscurity. Well we will be having some more layers of security to protect it. Anyway do you have any idea about how i can get to my solution?

Comment: I linked you the nan module in my first comment. And to generate the hash you can use the buildin `crypto` module.